# Using JodaModule - Object mapper

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I'm using spring-boot to pass an object as JSON via post

```
public class ObjectDTO dto {
  ...
}

@PutMapping("/api/get/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Integer> update(@PathVariable("id") int id, @RequestBody ObjectDTO dto) {
...
}
```

and

```
ObjectDTO object = new ObjectDTO();
...
ResponseEntity<Integer> restResult = restTemplate.exchange(APIBaseUrl+"get/{id}", HttpMethod.PUT, new HttpEntity<>(object), Integer.class, String.valueOf(object.getId()));
```

How can i use object mapper for ObjectDTO object?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to use object mapper for ObjectDTO ?

Comment: Because ObjectDTO has org.joda.time.LocalDateTime. When i get this parameter i found that they are reset to current time

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/46722936/1776132 ?